# change session variables back to $variable in php

Tags: php, variables, session

Ive been working with `$_session` to catch a variable and move my variable around my site.

```
variable = $a
$a = $_POST['pricex'] ;
```

`$a` gets made into a session

```
$_SESSION["coffee"] = $a;
```

variable is echod on another page.

```
echo $_SESSION['coffee'] ;
```

all the examples i've seen use the long `$_session["coffee"]` to query etc

how can i get session back to $a so i dont have to change my queries and classes

```
 $_SESSION['coffee'] = $a
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: read it into the var from `$_SESSION`? `$a = $_SESSION['coffee'];`

Comment: where does that go in the code?

Comment: Instead of `$_SESSION['coffee'] = $a` do `$a = $_SESSION['coffee'];`. The first variable is the one you want to set and the one after the `=` is what you are setting it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic assignment.

The variable you want to assign **to** goes on the **left**. The value (whether it be another variable, the return value of a function, a literal, or whatever) you want to assign goes on the **right**

```
$a =  $_SESSION['coffee'];
```

Comment: i get undefined index by doing that.

Comment: @DonQuery — Then you would have also got an undefined index when you had tried `echo $_SESSION['coffee'] ;`

Comment: @DonQuery — My point being that *something else changed* between you using the line of code here and the line of code I quoted in my previous comment.

Comment: it just doesnt like the $a = in front of the session.. i though tthis had more logic but doesnt work either.  $_SESSION["coffee"] = $a;

Comment: PHP [likes it just fine](https://repl.it/@dorward/stackoverflowcomquestions53192050). The problem is something else.

Comment: "i though tthis had more logic but doesnt work either. $_SESSION["coffee"] = $a" — See the second paragraph of this answer which explains the difference between the left and right hand sides of the `=` operator.

Comment: $_SESSION["coffee"] = $a;   this works just fine on the page and gives me the content of the $a variable which in this case = 500000 .   is there a way to echo $a     (stack can you stop sending on press of enter!! , very annoying)

Comment: That's how you put data *into* the session. You were asking about when you went to another page and wanted to take data *out* of the session.

Comment: wt hell..this works ,,thanks...shoudl i  delete this question though due to misunderstandings.... thx for your time.   echo $a = $_SESSION['coffee'] ;
echo $a